# Reading controls from previous page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have `Page1.aspx` containing

```
Name: <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" />
```

`Page2.aspx` tries to access its contents by

```
   TextBox txt2 = (TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("txt1");
```

However I end up getting an Object reference not set to instance of an object exception

Comment: Please check these links: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178140(v=vs.80).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Are you directing to page2.aspx with `Transfer` or cross page posting? Otherwise it wont work. See the [remark section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx)

Comment: If you need only 1 or 2 values of previous page then you can store the values in Cookie and pass the value by querystring. If you creating the object of previous page then all the data will be load, so it would decrease the performence.

Comment: you can achieve it using cross page post back. But remember, performance wise, it isn't good becuase it will also fire some events of the previous page (although you can try PreviousPagePostback check). So, use querystring or alternatives

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used `PreviousPage` before and have had success with this snippet of code I found elsewhere online (Can't remember where I found it!)

So..

**Option 1:**

On your first page you have your button that takes you to the second page, you need to set the `PostBackUrl` property to the new page url:

```
<asp:Button ID="button1" Runat="server" Text="submit" PostBackUrl="~/Page2.aspx" />
```

(*This is presuming that your 1st page is a form that redirects to your Page2.aspx*)

Then in the new page's code behind you need to write something along the lines of this:

```
public void page_load()
{
if(!IsPostBack)
{
TextBox tb = (TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("txt2");
Response.Write(tb.Text);}
}
```

You will need to transfer the value of the previous page's `txt2.Text` to a textbox or label on the new page if you are wanting to do any more postbacks on the second page, otherwise you will lose that value.

**Option 2:**

You could also use a Session variable surely to store your data?!

```
Session["text"] = txt2.Text;
```

Answer (score -2):

Once your'e in the new page, the last page is probably gone, I'd suggest transferring your data over the session.